ImageBind LLM checkpoint
I want to use imagebind llm model for my task, but I can not import llama and find out the checkpoints for ImageBind-LLM.

I installed all required packages and followed readme instruction on github to process imagebind llm, but it still has errors in my image.
here is github link of imagebind

Looks like you are running it on Google Colab. Knn_cuda package will require GPU runtimes. If you are using Colab CPU runtimes, it won't work. You can change it to GPU runtime by going to  You should change to a GPU runtime (Connect -> Change Runtime Type -> Chose the hardware type you prefer) and then try your script again.
